# Default port number will not change for my react app

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, port

Hi I am new to react and would like to change my react port number of 3000
as i have an express server running on the 3000.

So obviously i look through stackoverflow answers and i tried everything recommended.

1. i created a .env in root folder (public) and set the port to = 4000
2. tried the same in .env.development
3. i added:

   "scripts": {
   "start": "set PORT=3500 && react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build"
   }

in my json file.

but only to end up with below upon restart

Local:            http://localhost:3000
On Your Network:  http://192.168.2.19:3000

What could i possbily be missing in my app that its working for other ppl but not for me??
please let me know

Comment: Are you running Windows?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Mac/Linux the start command is slightly different:

```
"start": "PORT=3500 react-scripts start"
```

Comment: i am on windows

Comment: yes i am on windows